# Ecto.Migration with constraint - child/parent

Tags: postgresql, migration, constraints, ecto

I have an application in Elixir with news, which the user should be able to comment. Here my migration to create the comment functionality:

```
def change do
  create table(:news_comments, primary_key: false) do
    add :id, :uuid, primary_key: true
    add :news_id, references(:news, type: :uuid, on_delete: :nilify_all)
    add :comment_id, references(:comments, type: :uuid, on_delete: :nilify_all)
    add :parent_comment_id, references(:comments, type: :uuid, on_delete: :nilify_all)
  end
end
```

I want to allow sub comments for comments and would do this with a constraint. A user can comment a news by sending the `news_id` and `comment_id`. I want to allow to send sub comments, which I want to allow only for the same news. So I need an unique constraint for `news_id` and `comment_id`, no problem till now. But when a user sends a sub comment I want to assure, that the sub comment has the `news_id` and `parent_comment_id`, which are already saved in the database. Lets say I got a `news_comment` with `news_id = 1` and `comment_id = 1`, the database should only allow inserts with `news_id = 1` and `parent_comment_id = 1`. I don't want to handle this case in the code, because I think the database can handle it. Would be no problem with a stored procedure, but there should be a way to achieve this with a constraint, but no idea how.

The next case the constraint should handle is to allow only sub comments for comments without a `parent_comment_id`, because i don't want to allow sub comments for sub comments, like commenting on youtube. Multiple constraints are ok, just need a solution, else I need to handle it inside my code with some database requests which I would like to avoid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def up do
  execute "ALTER TABLE news_comments 
  ADD CONSTRAINT uc_news_comment UNIQUE (news_id, comment_id);"

  execute "ALTER TABLE news_comments 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (news_id, parent_comment_id) 
  REFERENCES news_comments(news_id, comment_id);"
end
```

Made the job.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your business logic, but it seems like you could do without the join tables to reduce complexity somewhat.

Instead of going...

```
news <- news_comments -> comment <- news_comments -> comment
```

...you could go...

```
news <- comment <- subcomment
```

...which would have tables like...

```
def change do
  create table(:comments, primary_key: false) do
    add :id, :uuid, primary_key: true
    add :news_id, references(:news, type: :uuid, on_delete: :nilify_all)
    add :body_text_or_whatever, :text
  end

  create table(:subcomments, primary_key: false) do
    add :id, :uuid, primary_key: true
    add :comment_id, references(:comments, type: :uuid, on_delete: :delete_all)
    add :body_text_or_whatever, :text
  end
end
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question -- which was how to set up a constraint for your join table -- but it seems like it would meet your business logic of news can have many comments, and subcomments can only be one layer deep.

Comment: This would reduce the complexity in the database, but not in the code. Keeping the table new_comments i just need one methode to add/remove comments/subcomments and only one view for the json response. Not only news can have comments, so i need a few tables like news_comments. I my case news can have many comments, some of the comments are subcomments. Your approach reduces the complexity of the database, but needs on more model, more code in the controllers and one more view. In the views I would also have to put more complexity, to flatten comments adn subcomments to one array.